# Unit testing 'pathlib.Path.is_file' in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I am new to unit testing in Python and have problems to get my tests running. I want to implement the following test class as shown in here: https://www.toptal.com/python/an-introduction-to-mocking-in-python, but slightly 
modified. 
Instead of using `os.path.isfile` I want to use `pathlib.Path.is_file`.

This is the actual class to test:

```
import os

from pathlib import Path

class FileUtils:

    @staticmethod
    def isFile(file):
        return Path(file).is_file()

    @staticmethod
    def deleteFile(file):
        if FileUtils.isFile(file):
            os.remove(file)
```

And this is the test class:

```
import mock, unittest

class FileUtilsTest(unittest.TestCase):

    testFilename = "filename"

    @mock.patch('FileUtils.Path')
    @mock.patch('FileUtils.os')
    def testDeleteFiles(self, osMock, pathMock):

        pathMock.is_file.return_value = False
        FileUtils.deleteFile(self.testFilename)
        self.assertFalse(osMock.remove.called, 'Failed to not remove the file if not present.')

        pathMock.is_file.return_value = True
        FileUtils.deleteFile(self.testFilename)
        osMock.remove.assert_called_with(self.testFilename)
```

This will lead to the following error message:

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

======================================================================
FAIL: testDeleteFile (FileUtilsTest.FileUtilsTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\mock\mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "...\FileUtilsTest.py", line 13, in testDeleteFile
    self.assertFalse(osMock.remove.called, 'Failed to not remove the file if not present.')
AssertionError: True is not false : Failed to not remove the file if not present.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

How can I test the method `FileUtils.deleteFile` by using `@mock.patch` decorators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that when you patch the symbol `Path` in the module, you're replacing the symbol for the constructor of `Path`. But `is_file` is not a attribute of the constructor - it's a attribute of the object returned by the constructor. The constructor is called, and you call `is_file` on the return value. So you need to mock that part as well. To do that, set a mock to be returned, when the `Path` symbol is invoked.

```
import mock, unittest

class FileUtilsTest(unittest.TestCase):

    testFilename = "filename"

    @mock.patch('FileUtils.Path')
    @mock.patch('FileUtils.os')
    def testDeleteFiles(self, osMock, pathMock):
        mock_path = MagicMock()
        pathMock.return_value = mock_path

        mock_path.is_file.return_value = False
        FileUtils.deleteFile(self.testFilename)
        self.assertFalse(osMock.remove.called, 'Failed to not remove the file if not present.')

        mock_path.is_file.return_value = True
        FileUtils.deleteFile(self.testFilename)
        osMock.remove.assert_called_with(self.testFilename)
```